# sentence structure noun and adjective

Tags: grammar

ゴリラは争いを 嫌う温和 な動物で、こちらが危害を加えないかぎり、人を襲うことはまずない。

in this phrase ゴリラは争いを嫌う温和な動物で,   争い is a object   and 嫌う温和 is a modified noun/adjective. How a noun is associated with noun/adjective ?? can anyone explain this sentence structure.Any similar examples also

Answer (score 2):

> 争い is a object and 嫌う温和 is a modified noun/adjective.

争い is the object of the verb 嫌う.
争いを嫌う ("don't like fighting") is a relative clause that modifies 温和な動物 ("gentle animals").

> ゴリラは［争いを嫌う］温和な動物で...
>   *Gorillas are gentle animals ［that don't like fighting］, and...*

---

Alternatively, you could parse it this way:

> ゴリラは［争いを嫌う］［温和な］動物で...
>   *Gorillas are [gentle] animals ［that don't like fighting］, and...*

A relative clause 争いを嫌う and a na-adjective 温和な both modify 動物.

---

You could refer to this thread for the same sentence structure: [その日の朝は、いつもと全く変わらない、平凡な朝だった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54742/9831)

Answer (score 0):

I can’t understand why you separate the way because my English skill is poor. Sorry.
My separation as a native Japanese speaker is

ゴリラは  争いを  嫌う  温厚な  動物で、

main structure of this phrase is 「ゴリラは温厚な動物(Gorilla is gentle animal)」.
「争いを嫌う(they hate fights) 」is adding for explaining how they are gentle.

Similar example is I think
「それは矛盾を孕む難しい問題だ。」

I don’t know this is right answer to you, But I hope this help you a little bit.

Comment: are we modifying this  孕む(verb) with the noun ??

Comment: @Sam Sorry I now know what is “modify” means. Yes, 孕む is adjoins form of 孕む(verb) corresponding to the “問題”.  My example is also able to interpret that 難しい is inserted into 矛盾を孕む問題(矛盾を孕む modifies 問題). your example is also the same.(争いを嫌う modified 動物 and 温厚な is inserted).